# GraphQL filter on child parameters

Tags: go, graphql

I am trying to implement Trainer-Course Relationship. Having trouble creating resolvers for the following query.

```
query GetCourseOfTrainer {
    course {
        title
        trainer(Id : "911") {
             id
             name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to fetch two entities course and trainer. You would need two
resolvers, one for course and another for trainer.

In order to resolver courses, we need to have separate resolver under Query.

```
    Query : {
              course(root, args, context, info) {
                  console.log(args)
              }
      }
```

To resolve trainer inside Course, the resolver for trainer would come under Course type resolver.

```
    resolver = {
    Course : {    
     trainer: (parent, {Id}, { dataSources }, info) => {
              dataSources.someSource.someMethod(Id);
     }
    }
   }
```

Here Course is the type of course in Query and trainer is the field from Query.

Comment: Thanks, though i'm trying to implement it with golang using this https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql library. Any idea how to add trainer inside Course resolver in golang.